# How to extract 4096 ssh key format from existing 2048 ssh key in window 10

Tags: ssh

How to extract or get the 4096 ssh key format from existing 2048 ssh key in window 10.

As i am want to use one web development tools, it requires only 4096 ssh key format, if i have generated new ssh key then old environments and tools won't work so i don't want to break current system workflow.

Is there any way to generate new 4096 ssh key without overwrite the existing ssh key?

or

Can we maintain multiple ssh key in our system?

Please help us.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answers. We can maintain multiple ssh keys in our system.

While generating the ssh key, we have to give unique key name which shouldn't be old key name. We can maintain separate folder for new ssh keys.

PS : Please take backup of existing ssh keys available in  ".ssh/" folder before generate new keys.

This command is used to generate ssh key : `ssh-keygen -b 4096`